# I have this type of json format data

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "fertilizer":[{"pg1":"-21.259515860749435","pg2":"24.741169305724725","lastyearlastmonth":"764.119","currentmonth":"601.671","currentyearytd":"5735.1","lastyearytd":"4597.6","pname":"Urea","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-20.53085432388131","pg2":"9.258986807905458","lastyearlastmonth":"631.435","currentmonth":"501.796","currentyearytd":"2227.9","lastyearytd":"2039.1","pname":"DAP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"67.37546062508531","pg2":"51.07126222636238","lastyearlastmonth":"36.635","currentmonth":"61.318","currentyearytd":"648.7","lastyearytd":"429.4","pname":"CAN","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-49.542998848640515","pg2":"7.7561388653683245","lastyearlastmonth":"112.91","currentmonth":"56.971","currentyearytd":"636.3","lastyearytd":"590.5","pname":"NP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-53.39393939393939","pg2":"-2.1138211382113776","lastyearlastmonth":"4.95","currentmonth":"2.307","currentyearytd":"60.2","lastyearytd":"61.5","pname":"NPK","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-14.652234166073644","pg2":"-5.41561712846349","lastyearlastmonth":"26.699","currentmonth":"22.787","currentyearytd":"75.1","lastyearytd":"79.4","pname":"SSP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"123.88827636898196","pg2":"239.6551724137931","lastyearlastmonth":"2.721","currentmonth":"6.092","currentyearytd":"39.4","lastyearytd":"11.6","pname":"SOP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"58.21359223300969","pg2":"134.07407407407408","lastyearlastmonth":"2.575","currentmonth":"4.074","currentyearytd":"31.6","lastyearytd":"13.5","pname":"MOP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":null,"pg2":null,"lastyearlastmonth":"0","currentmonth":"0","currentyearytd":"0","lastyearytd":"0","pname":"MAP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":null,"pg2":null,"lastyearlastmonth":"0","currentmonth":"0","currentyearytd":"0","lastyearytd":"0","pname":"TSP","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-56.21508379888268","pg2":"-0.6802721088435351","lastyearlastmonth":"2.864","currentmonth":"1.254","currentyearytd":"14.6","lastyearytd":"14.7","pname":"AS","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-20.609372141004858","pg2":"20.81536932387274","lastyearlastmonth":"1584.91","currentmonth":"1258.27","currentyearytd":"9468.82","lastyearytd":"7837.43","pname":"Total","mmonth":"11","period":"11","myear":"2017"}],
    "automobile":[{"pg1":"11.009369676320272","pg2":"22.30648472406714","lastyearlastmonth":"14088","currentmonth":"15639","currentyearytd":"50641","lastyearytd":"41405","pname":"PC","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"2597.0588235294117","pg2":"1874.4827586206895","lastyearlastmonth":"34","currentmonth":"917","currentyearytd":"2863","lastyearytd":"145","pname":"SUV","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"15.686274509803921","pg2":"14.290401968826908","lastyearlastmonth":"1938","currentmonth":"2242","currentyearytd":"6966","lastyearytd":"6095","pname":"LCV","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"58.64978902953587","pg2":"34.17569193742479","lastyearlastmonth":"474","currentmonth":"752","currentyearytd":"2230","lastyearytd":"1662","pname":"Truck","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-60.57692307692307","pg2":"-34.74320241691843","lastyearlastmonth":"104","currentmonth":"41","currentyearytd":"216","lastyearytd":"331","pname":"Bus","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"74.47245017584994","pg2":"99.92364469330617","lastyearlastmonth":"3412","currentmonth":"5953","currentyearytd":"15710","lastyearytd":"7858","pname":"Tractor","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"14.790290676232942","pg2":"27.133399110577265","lastyearlastmonth":"119308","currentmonth":"136954","currentyearytd":"444541","lastyearytd":"349665","pname":"2 Wheel","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"33.41478313989004","pg2":"30.228058051140287","lastyearlastmonth":"4911","currentmonth":"6552","currentyearytd":"18844","lastyearytd":"14470","pname":"3 Wheel","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"17.04856787048568","pg2":"26.917829782768393","lastyearlastmonth":"16060","currentmonth":"18798","currentyearytd":"60470","lastyearytd":"47645","pname":"Total Cars","mmonth":"9","period":"3","myear":"2017"}],
    "oilmkting":[{"pg1":"-100","pg2":"-100.00000","lastyearlastmonth":"0.102","currentmonth":"0","currentyearytd":"0.0","lastyearytd":"0.4","pname":"100LL","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-5.129426108196923","pg2":"-0.04207","lastyearlastmonth":"59.803999999999995","currentmonth":"56.73639801025391","currentyearytd":"237.6","lastyearytd":"237.7","pname":"JP-1","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"1194.9860724233984","pg2":"104.22535","lastyearlastmonth":"1.436","currentmonth":"18.596","currentyearytd":"58.0","lastyearytd":"28.4","pname":"JP-8","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"8.688345498555524","pg2":"15.40422","lastyearlastmonth":"575.4939999999999","currentmonth":"625.494907043457","currentyearytd":"2580.9","lastyearytd":"2236.4","pname":"MS","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"179.72428859212695","pg2":"209.85915","lastyearlastmonth":"3.8990000000000005","currentmonth":"10.906450012207031","currentyearytd":"44.0","lastyearytd":"14.2","pname":"HOBC","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":null,"pg2":null,"lastyearlastmonth":"0","currentmonth":"0","currentyearytd":"0.0","lastyearytd":"0.0","pname":"E-10","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"52.374035671418994","pg2":"11.97917","lastyearlastmonth":"7.263999999999999","currentmonth":"11.068449951171875","currentyearytd":"43.0","lastyearytd":"38.4","pname":"Kerosene","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"1.599296460019584","pg2":"18.32285","lastyearlastmonth":"836.0709999999998","currentmonth":"849.4422539062501","currentyearytd":"3142.3","lastyearytd":"2655.7","pname":"HSD","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"9.73656730601859","pg2":"61.22449","lastyearlastmonth":"1.526","currentmonth":"1.6745800170898437","currentyearytd":"7.9","lastyearytd":"4.9","pname":"LDO","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"4.033703464379442","pg2":"-6.30181","lastyearlastmonth":"866.287","currentmonth":"901.2304487304688","currentyearytd":"3413.8","lastyearytd":"3643.4","pname":"FO","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"5.2411828169554875","pg2":"7.54227","lastyearlastmonth":"2351.8830000000007","currentmonth":"2475.149487670898","currentyearytd":"9527.6","lastyearytd":"8859.4","pname":"Total","mmonth":"10","period":"4","myear":"2017"}],
    "cement":[{"pg1":"4.941027677946538","pg2":"12.29975","lastyearlastmonth":"3554.888","currentmonth":"3730.536","currentyearytd":"22242.2","lastyearytd":"19806.1","pname":"Domestic","mmonth":"12","period":"6","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"-11.24660806265538","pg2":"-17.33874","lastyearlastmonth":"369.258","currentmonth":"327.729","currentyearytd":"2406.6","lastyearytd":"2911.4","pname":"Exports","mmonth":"12","period":"6","myear":"2017"},{"pg1":"3.417788227043532","pg2":"8.50138","lastyearlastmonth":"3924.146","currentmonth":"4058.265","currentyearytd":"24648.8","lastyearytd":"22717.5","pname":"Total Sales","mmonth":"12","period":"6","myear":"2017"}]

}
```

I have four different table fertilizer, automobile, oil marketing and cement and I want to  data display in a table using for loop  but data not read one by one

```
foreach ($data as $nt) 
    {
        echo "<tr class='{$dispval} {$boldrow}' >";
        echo "<td>{$nt[pname]}</td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright'>" . number_format($nt[lastyearlastmonth],1) . " </td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright'>" . number_format($nt[currentmonth],1) . " </td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright'>" . number_format($nt[pg1],1) . " </td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright'>" . number_format($nt[lastyearytd],1) . " </td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright' >" . number_format($nt[currentyearytd],1) . " </td>";
        echo "<td class='txtright'>" . number_format($nt[pg2],1) . " </td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to iterate through your data if not "one by one"?

Comment: Im using loop and i show data in ferlizer table cement table oil market table i have created four seperate table im using four like like show foreach $data as $nt .how do i display data in under the table <td> tag

Comment: I have no idea what your aim is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$fCount = count($json['fertilizer']);           
for( $i = 0; $i<$fCount; $i++ ) {

    echo "<tr  >";
    echo "<td>".$json['fertilizer'][$i]['pname']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['lastyearlastmonth'],1)." </td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['currentmonth'],1). " </td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['pg1'],1). " </td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['lastyearytd'],1). " </td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['currentyearytd'],1). " </td>";
    echo "<td class='txtright'>". number_format($json['fertilizer'][$i]['pg2'],1). " </td>";

    echo "</tr  >";
}
```

Store json response in $jsonData variable
similarly add other loops for automobile, oilmkting & cement
Enjoy...